# Conditionals(else if) in ejs file throwing a syntax error

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I am unable to use the else if condition in my ejs file.

```
<% if(locals.user && (locals.user.id == post.user.id)){ %>
  <small>
    <a href="/comments/destroy/?comment_id=<%= comment.id %>&post_id=<%= post.user.id %>">
      <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </a>
  </small>
<% } else if(locals.user && (locals.user.id == post.user.id)){ %>
  <small>
    <a href="/comments/destroy/<%= comment.id %>">
      <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
    </a>
  </small>
<% } %>
```

It throws a syntax error for some reason. If I remove else from the code it works. How can I  fix this?

Comment: It works for me. Please share the syntax error that you got.

Comment: Unrelated, but both IF and ELSE conditions are exactly the same.